# Trying to concatenate or join rows while discarding others in notepad++

Tags: mysql, notepad++

I have hundreds of "records" of data that follow this 14 row syntax.

```
interface vdsl 1/2/11 is IS and up
  Description                     : 9073762319_VDTV_15_1
  Rate Mode                       : Adapt at startup
  DMT Standard                    : 993.2A (VDSL2 Region A)
  Band Profile                    : 17A
  Far-End Vendor                  : BDCM (ver A2pv6F039n)
  Framing                         : EFM
  Estimated Length             ft : 2361
  Up Time                     sec : 67461
  Initializations                 : 18
                                   Downstream            Upstream              
  Line Rate                  kbps : 25967                 1474
  Payload Rate               kbps : 18000                 1000
  Max Attain Rate            kbps : 53993                 17904
```

I am trying to put (concatenate?) rows 1, 12, and 13 out of each record on the same row and discard all the other rows. Every 'record' has the same common row 'headings', ie, "interface" and "Line Rate" and "Payload Rate" will be in every "record" although the values that follow those 'headings' will change as the "records" change.

Appreciate any advice/examples. Thanks.

Comment: this is how the data appears naturally:

Answer (score 0):

You are using Notepad++ (it's in the title, but not in the tags)?

With it, you can create macro's. If you can find a sequence of commands (for instance, perhaps even  include searches for 'Downstream' to jump to the right header), you can make quite advanced macro's (see the menu 'Macro').

Also, you can make smart use of Ctrl+Arrows to jump whole words, and Home and End to jump to line endings. That way, you can write a macro that is consistent for every record. Once you have that (and make sure it ends at the start of the next), you can stop recording and run that macro repeatedly.

I'd give you the exact sequence of keystrokes, but it's not exactly clear to me what you want, and it's probably just as easy to find out yourself than to exactly type them all over.